# How can I fetch table data using node-rfc SAP's BAPI

Tags: node.js, saprfc, bapi

I need to fetch table data from a SAP system with node-rfc library. Need help where I can pass table name or parameters so that I can get proper data to build Node.js API.

Do you have any idea what is wrong? I'm out of ideas :(

```
const noderfc = require("node-rfc");

const client = new noderfc.Client({ dest: "MME" });

(async () => {
  try {
    // unlike the connection acquired from pool,
    // the direct client connection is initially closed
    await client.open();

    // invoke ABAP function module, passing structure and table parameters

    // ABAP structure
    const abap_structure = {
      RFCINT4: 345,
      RFCFLOAT: 1.23456789,
      RFCCHAR4: "ABCD",
      RFCDATE: "20180625", // ABAP date format
      // or RFCDATE: new Date('2018-06-25'), // as JavaScript Date object, with clientOption "date"
    };
    // ABAP table
    let abap_table = [abap_structure];

    const result = await client.call("STFC_STRUCTURE", {
      IMPORTSTRUCT: abap_structure,
      RFCTABLE: abap_table,
    });

    // check the result
    console.log(result);
    GetDataTableFromRFCTable(result.RFCTABLE);
  } catch (err) {
    // connection and invocation errors
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

// Assuming DataTable, GetDataTableFromRFCTable, etc., are defined elsewhere
function GetDataTableFromRFCTable(lrfcTable) {
  console.log("lrfcTable", lrfcTable);
  
}
```

Response I am getting like.

```
{
  ECHOSTRUCT: {
    RFCFLOAT: 1.23456789,
    RFCCHAR1: '',
    RFCINT2: 0,
    RFCINT1: 0,
    RFCCHAR4: 'ABCD',
    RFCINT4: 345,
    RFCHEX3: <Buffer 00 00 00>,
    RFCCHAR2: '',
    RFCTIME: '000000',
    RFCDATE: '20180625',
    RFCDATA1: '',
    RFCDATA2: ''
  },
  RESPTEXT: 'SAP R/3 Rel. 750   Sysid: QP3      Date: 20240105   Time: 130159',
  IMPORTSTRUCT: {
    RFCFLOAT: 1.23456789,
    RFCCHAR1: '',
    RFCINT2: 0,
    RFCINT1: 0,
    RFCCHAR4: 'ABCD',
    RFCINT4: 345,
    RFCHEX3: <Buffer 00 00 00>,
    RFCCHAR2: '',
    RFCTIME: '000000',
    RFCDATE: '20180625',
    RFCDATA1: '',
    RFCDATA2: ''
  },
  RFCTABLE: [
    {
      RFCFLOAT: 1.23456789,
      RFCCHAR1: '',
      RFCINT2: 0,
      RFCINT1: 0,
      RFCCHAR4: 'ABCD',
      RFCINT4: 345,
      RFCHEX3: <Buffer 00 00 00>,
      RFCCHAR2: '',
      RFCTIME: '000000',
      RFCDATE: '20180625',
      RFCDATA1: '',
      RFCDATA2: ''
    },
    {
      RFCFLOAT: 2.23456789,
      RFCCHAR1: 'X',
      RFCINT2: 1,
      RFCINT1: 1,
      RFCCHAR4: 'QP3',
      RFCINT4: 346,
      RFCHEX3: <Buffer f1 f2 f3>,
      RFCCHAR2: 'YZ',
      RFCTIME: '130159',
      RFCDATE: '20240105',
      RFCDATA1: '',
      RFCDATA2: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It "works fine" from my point of view. Please be precise on "what is wrong". Avoid saying just "doesn't work" or "is wrong" without details, it's very subjective. Tell what you obtain, how you obtain it, and what you expect. Thank you.

Comment: HI @SandraRossi, I need create node API, my expectation  is  to how i can show table data with the help of Node-RFC. 

Read all table name and table data form SAP,

please HELP OUT